# Self managed cluster with openshift and azure

Tags: azure, openshift

I am building a platform (self managed openshift platform on azure). Anyhow I am getting the below error while validating the deployment.
I am not sure, whether it has to do something with azure or openshift, to me it looks like it is azure, but I am not sure.

> The specified blob does not exist. RequestId:5f8eeb2c-001e-0043-2a5a-dfe5c2000000

Comment: Can you please update your question and add the DeploymentConfig?

Comment: Hello  Thomas, I am trying to Build Self managed openshift cluster on microsoft azure using GUI , where we can provide all the information's like below 

1) Vm Admin username
2) SSH Key for the vm user
3) Subscriptions 
4) resource group 
5)Location
6) OCP cluster name Prefix
7) Key vault RG , vault name  etc etc 
8)Subscriptions from redhat 
And on last page when we submit the button for validation , i am getting error saying "Unable to download deployment content from " so and so url " and the content is below 

The specified blob does not exist. RequestId:5f8eeb2c-001e-0043-2a5a

Comment: I would like to share the screenshots and logs but i am new to the stackflow so i dont know how i can do that

Comment: @ThomasSchwärzl Hi Thomas, you got some time today ?